# Manualy created HtmlDocument.DocumentNode returns null from InnerHtml

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, nullreferenceexception

try to build HTML manually from code. code, that builds html:

```
            public string ParseFromRoot(RootItem root)
            {
                if (root == null || root.Children.Count == 0)
                    return string.Empty;

                var document = new HtmlDocument();

                foreach (var item in root.Children)
                    ParseNode(document, document.DocumentNode, item);

                return document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
            }

         private HtmlNode ParseNode(HtmlDocument document, HtmlNode parentNode, ItemBase item)
        {
            var node = DefineNode(document, item);

            parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);

            if (item.Children.Count == 0)
                return node;

            foreach (var child in item.Children)
                ParseNode(document, node, child);

            return node;
        }
```

in that case on the ready document, I've got Null reference when trying to access `document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml`. But InnerText reflects actual text, and all is okay?

In case I document.LoadHtml("") the same html, `document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml` returns real html without exception?

html:

```
<p>dsgwegsdrgsrdeg</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>just <strong>typihere</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ol>
   <li>some list</li>
   <li>another list</li>
</ol>
<p>j</p>
```

[image: debug info]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in this line:

```
parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
```

we need to replace it with

```
parentNode.AppendChild(node);
```